# How to view ggplot2 output when using nvim-R in WSL2

Tags: r, ggplot2, neovim

I am trying to create plots with ggplot2 using nvim-R within WSL2 and they just don't show up.
Is there a way to e.g. view them e.g. in the browswer without saving them explicitely?

EDIT:
when I add

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

to my .zshrc, I get the following error:

```
Error in .External2(C_X11, d$display, d$width, d$height, d$pointsize,  :
      unable to start device X11cairo
```

Comment: Not an answer, but you could try using Visual Studio Code + [vscode-R](https://github.com/Ikuyadeu/vscode-R) and enable the session watcher feature

Comment: Yeah the whole point is that I want to make the switch from VS Code to vim right now but thank you, maybe this is useful at some point :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself, which was to install the latest preview build of WSL2 (requires Windows insider), which supports gui applications.